# The app Facebook has violated its self-enforced StrictMode policy

Tags: facebook, crashes, miui

I am using `Red Mi Note` running on `MIUI5`. Recently, I am getting this error:

> The app Facebook (process.com.facebook.katana) has violated its self-enforced StrictMode Policy.

What does it mean? How can I resolve the issue? It becomes frustrating when the error comes as it continues to pop-up and doesn't hide on pressing <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

<sup>(Click the image to see its larger variant)</sup>

The Error message doesn't have any specific time to occur even the error is not app specific. It occurs randomly on different situations.

Comment: I have downloaded the app from play store only not from the Any other sources. And I have messenger and Facebook app both installed. And i am confused whether this error is because of Facebook App or due to messenger App

Comment: `com.facebook.katana` is the Facebook app.

Comment: Seeing that the package name is `com.facebook.katana`, I believe it's Facebook, not Messenger. Does this happen randomly, or on a certain condition? (on certain time? while using certain app? etc).

Comment: The error message doesn't have a fix time to come...In a day it comes randomly 4 to 6 times. I tried uninstalling also but it comes again

Comment: Sometimes it comes when i play games and sometimes when i use apps,... as far as i am concern and studied about the occurence of this error it is not app dependent...

Answer (score 1):

In the dex provided by Facebook app, on `com.facebook.katana/app_secondary_program_dex` folder, we find a lot of references to the [`StrictMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html).

So, for short, if a programmer use `StrictMode`, he has a reason. Basically while forking a busy process (read: animation, reading data, dictionary values for data, open a new fragment or activity on main thread), instead of crashing app there must be put (show) a message to user to inform about waiting or terminating app.

In the particular case of Facebook app, there's `/facebook/strictmode/setter/Policy$All` and also `errorreporting/StrictModeException`. So the message comes after raising an exception. We can just assume an activity take too long or force running in main thread.

The key word is in `MessengerApp`. We may think about Facebook and Messenger app as separate apps, but the truth is Facebook has embeded `FbandroidMessengerAppModule` functions calls in it's core and also performs some logical checking as for example:

- IsMessageBroadcastEnabled
- IsMessageBroadcastGkEnabled
- IsMessengerAppIconBadgingEnabled
- IsMessengerAppIconBadgingGkEnabled
- IsMessengerBlockingEnabled
- IsMessengerFlatBufferEnabled
- IsMessengerLoggedOutAppIconBadgingEnabled
- IsMessengerPhotoEditDefaultModeDrawing
- IsMessengerPhotoEditDefaultModeDrawingGk
- IsMessengerSonyAppIconBadgingEnabled
- IsMessengerSyncEnabled
- IsMessengerThreadShortcutsEnabled

Without access to debug console, I can't predict what cause that kind of message (is it about reading values from stored DB, or are some DB files corrupted, user switched from a WiFi connection to internet connection while parsing some data ?), but my advice is to make sure Facebook app and Messenger for FB are clean installed and updated to the latest version.

Sometime a game app can embed Facebook SDK to share data and try to access data without user FB permissions set on that game (app), or is written badly so it can raise some exception (**I think this indeed your problem**).

Answer (score -1):

This is because of ROOTING.You should UNROOT.

Comment: Any reference that could backup your answer?